# app() helper return different structure on server

Tags: json, laravel

i have this code

```
app('getHomeContent')
```

locally it returns

```
{#2999 ▼
  +"slider_title": "For every student, every classroom. Real results."
  +"slider_text": "Build skills with courses, certificates, and degrees online from world-class universities and companies"
  +"testimonial_title": "What Our Student Have To Say"
...
```

but on server
return

```
{#2999 ▼
  +"main": array:127 [▼
     +"slider_title": "For every student, every classroom. Real results."
  +"slider_text": "Build skills with courses, certificates, and degrees online from world-class universities and companies"
  +"testimonial_title": "What Our Student Have To Say"
....
```

the added `"main:"` causes issues as locally i don't have to type it at all to access the data ! how to fix  this ? what makes response different from server to local

Comment: Can you show the `getHomeContent` contents? Also, try doing `php artisan app:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` on your server.

Comment: That's isn't content as mentioned in post
```
{#2999 ▼
  +"slider_title": "For every student, every classroom. Real results."
  +"slider_text": "Build skills with courses, certificates, and degrees online from world-class universities and companies"
  +"testimonial_title": "What Our Student Have To Say"
  +"active_status": "1"
  +"created_by": "1"
  +"updated_by": "1"
  +"category_title": "Find videos courses on almost any topic to build career."
  +"category_sub_title": "Enjoy lifetime access to courses on our website and app."
 .....
```
just a bunch of key=>value items

Comment: i cleared cache/config and everything, the response is different locally and on server, the added "main:" is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way to go about this, instead of using `app()` to get content.

Here's what I would suggest so you get the same results everytime.

First, create a `helper.php` file in your `app` directory.

Second, add the following code in the `helper.php` file:

```
<?php 
    
function getHomeContent() {
    return [
      'slider_title' => 'title',
      'slider_text' => 'text',
      ...
    ]
}
```

Finally, go to your `composer.json` file and add the following

```
"autoload": {
    ...
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helper.php" // <---- this file
    ]
},
```

After doing `composer dump`, you can go anywhere and use `getHomeContent()` directly.

Comment: this line is present in tons of files in the project, so i cannot switch to a different way, i didn't write it's code so it would be easier to make it work as it's

Comment: If you use an IDE or a good editor, you can **search all** for all instances of `app('getHomeContent')` in your project and replace it with `getHomeContent()` pretty fast.